# How to get functions.php work with postname permalink?

Tags: permalinks

I have been looking for why I am able to use all permalink options except for postname, and have found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112829/why-would-numeric-permalinks-work-but-postname-wont) question and answer to be the likely reason why.

However unfortunately the person who answered did not explain what to do, merely that the custom taxonomies should be 'properly done'. I just installed my WP yesterday, and I haven't done any custom taxonomies. What am I supposed to do here?